Having trouble with eyebrows clipping properly

Im trying to rig the model's eyebrow which is a separate mesh. I tried data transfer so the face and eyebrow would be in perfect sync but it didn't work and I cant figure out how to get the weight paint on the face just right so the eyebrow stops clipping. I don't know what else to try

Add a Solidify modifier to eyebrows, to avoid clipping with thickness.

I dont know what that did but it just made things worse. It stretched out and got thick. The eyebrows just completely deformed.

Check and recalculate your normals (Shift N) and Apply rotation and scale (Ctrl A).

uhhh I dont know how that helps.... like I said in the main post they're separate meshes. The eyebrows clip into the head when it moves. I want to make both parts follow each other like its natural to avoid clipping....What do normals have to do with it?

Inverted normals can twist when using solidify modifier.
